# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, tripledes

Admin please don't mark it as duplicate read my question completely. I am encrypting and decrypting some text but while running in same file with main its running fine but when i call its encrypt and decrypt function from outside. Its giving an error at runtime. I am attaching the code.
    package desede;

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

import security.SHA256Algo;
import shradhafinalwiddesign.UpdateFile;
import shradhafinalwiddesign.UserRegistration;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Simple TripleDES Encrypt/Decrypt Test 
 * sha1, utf-8, no padding
 *
 * uses commons-codec-1.6 
 * javac -cp :commons-codec-1.6.jar TripleDESTest.java
 * java -cp :commons-codec-1.6.jar TripleDESTest 
 */

public class TripleDesDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String text = "textToEncrypt";
        UserRegistration user = new UserRegistration() ;
        user.setlUsername("tarunv") ;
        user.setAnswer("tommysdsfdsfsd") ;
        user.setLastaccess("pets namesdfsfds") ;
        user.setLpassword("computersdfdsfd") ;

        String h1 = SHA256Algo.createHash(user.getlUsername()) ;
        String h2 = SHA256Algo.createHash(user.getLpassword()) ;
        String h3 = SHA256Algo.createHash(user.getAnswer()) ;

        String hash1 = UpdateFile.modifyHashValue(h1).substring(0, 24) ;
        String hash2 = UpdateFile.modifyHashValue(h2) ;
        String hash3 = UpdateFile.modifyHashValue(h3) ;

        System.out.println("    key1 : "+hash1.length()+"    key2 : "+hash2.length()+"   key3 : "+hash3.length());
        byte[] arr = toByteArray(user) ;

        byte[] codedtext = TripleDesDemo._encrypt(arr,"tarunvermacdac@gmail.com");
        byte[] codedtext1 = TripleDesDemo._encrypt(codedtext,"tarun.spicyabc@gmail.com");
        byte[] codedtext2 = TripleDesDemo._encrypt(codedtext1,"direct_tarun@yahoo.co.in");

        writeSmallBinaryFile(codedtext2, "tarun.bat") ;
        byte[] texttoDecrypt = readSmallBinaryFile("tarun.bat");

        byte[] decodedtext = TripleDesDemo._decrypt(texttoDecrypt,"direct_tarun@yahoo.co.in");
        byte[] decodedtext1 = TripleDesDemo._decrypt(decodedtext,"tarun.spicyabc@gmail.com");
        byte[] decodedtext2 = TripleDesDemo._decrypt(decodedtext1,"tarunvermacdac@gmail.com");

        System.out.println(codedtext + " ---> " + toObject(decodedtext2));

      }


    public static byte[] _encrypt(byte[] plainTextBytes, String secretKey) throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getBytes();

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        //byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
        byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        byte [] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
        //String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);

        return base64Bytes ;
    }

    public static byte[] _decrypt(byte[] encryptedText, String secretKey) throws Exception {

        //byte[] message = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
        byte[] message = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
        byte[] keyBytes = secretKey.getBytes();
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");

        Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);
        return plainText ;
        //return toObject(plainText);
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(UserRegistration obj) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            oos.flush();
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } finally {
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    public static UserRegistration toObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        UserRegistration obj = null;
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        try {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            obj = (UserRegistration) ois.readObject();
        } finally {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public static byte[] readSmallBinaryFile(String aFileName) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        return Files.readAllBytes(path);
    }

    public static void writeSmallBinaryFile(byte[] aBytes, String aFileName) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(aFileName);
        Files.write(path, aBytes); //creates, overwrites
    }
}
```

The code is running fine with main but not when i call its function from other class which is in other package. Here is the exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64   at desede.TripleDesAlgo._encrypt(TripleDesAlgo.java:81)
```

And this is .classpath file

    
        
        
        
        
        
    
[image: Here is screenshot of my package explorer]
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 16):

You are missing commons-codec.jar. Download it from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi.
Then add it project build path. To do that right click the project, click Properties, click "Java Build Path", open "Library" tab, and click "Add External JARs...".

Or if you are using maven add dependency for

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i am using commons-codec-1.9 already and i have also set this for build path and its running fine with main. But not working outside. And i am not using ant or maven just eclipse.

Comment: You mean when you run the app outside of eclipse? In that case try java -cp c:\lib\*; com.company.Main, and put the jars inside lib.

Comment: no this file is having main method so we can run that file but when i am using it in the same project but different package its not working. Yesterday it was working by mistake i removed the related jar which is commons-codec-1.9 jar but when i add it back its not working when i call it from different java file which is in the same project but in different package.

Comment: if you add the jar back, try Project>Clean. if this doesn't work, attach a screenshot of your Project>Properties>Build path, to make sure the jar is there.

Comment: I was going through a similar question and someone suggested to make  it available at run time, thus adding to WEB-INF/lib can help. [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342163/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64)