# Class not found exception after deploying grails app to wildfly

Tags: grails, deployment, groovy, base64, wildfly

After deploying my grails application to wildfly i am getting this error wherever i am using base64 class

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/codec/binary/Base64

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246756/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64) stack overflow question may help.

Comment: @StephenDiMarco thankz for the link but it did not solved my problem..i hade another solution for the same.

Comment: @StephenDiMarco - I explicitly attached the jar in Lib folder which was not being build at the time of deployment.