# Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils

Tags: java, android, apache

I am having issues with app crashing and giving this stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils;
                      at com.ryko.fstwo.wrapper.DigestUtilsWrapper.sha1(DigestUtilsWrapper.java:7)
...
Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils" on path: <really long path name>
```

I have gone through all the threads on here I can find about this problem, but cant find a resolution. In my libs folder I have commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, In my dependencies section on `build.gradle` I have

`compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'` and

`compile files('libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar')`.

I have read through these but can't find a working solution
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126567/method-not-found-using-digestutils-in-android), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30259141/how-to-add-apache-commons-collections-in-android-studio-gradle), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342163/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64) and many others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that you need a dependency to [commons-codec](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec). It is available in maven central repo.

For example, add this to the dependencies section of your `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.10'
```

Or you you prefer the shorter option:

```
compile group: 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
```

Comment: I tried this but still same error. I have Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils" on path: <some really long  path> at bottom of stack trace that I shoulld include in original question if it helps

Comment: If you you download the jar file from maven central and unpack it you will see that the class is there. There is something wrong with the way that you package and run your application... Maybe you may provide extra details about this. The class is certainly within the jar file.

Answer (score 1):

you need have changes，such as

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
}
```