# RestAssured - TestNG testing RestfulAPI throws connection timeout error

Tags: testng, rest-assured

I am using TestNG with RestAssured framework to test RestAPI's.

The moment the execution hits this line, httpRequest.request, it throws connection timeout error

Am I missing anything in that line? It didn't throw any syntax error.

```
   import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
   import static io.restassured.RestAssured.ntlm; 
   import static io.restassured.RestAssured.basic; 
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
   import io.restassured.RestAssured;
   import io.restassured.http.Method;
   import io.restassured.response.Response;
   import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;


  public class RestApi_Incidents {

@BeforeMethod
 public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("before method");

}

@Test
void GetIncidentAPI(){      

    try{


    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://xxx/api/data/v8.2";
     RestAssured.port = 80;
     RestAssured.basePath = "/incident";
     RestAssured.authentication = basic("userid", "pwd!");
     //RestAssured.authentication = ntlm("uid", "pws!", null, "uat");   

     RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();

      Response response =httpRequest.get();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){

        System.out.println(ex.toString());

    }   

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "https://xxx/api/data/v8.2/";
 RestAssured.port = 80;
 RestAssured.basePath = "/incidents/resource/HealthCheckApp";
 RestAssured.authentication = basic("username", "password");
 RestAssured.authentication = ntlm("myuserid", null, null, "uat");   
 RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
 Response response =httpRequest.get("/DetailsView");
```

Comment: Arun, I modified the code and I am gettting connection timeout error. please see the modified code in the original post

Answer (score 0):

**You can refactor your accord as given below. I'm not able to replicate connection Time out error as Host is not available on my local**

```
package api.application.zippopotam;

import io.restassured.authentication.AuthenticationScheme;
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.ntlm;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;


public class RestApi_Incidents {

    public static RequestSpecification requestSpecification ;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println("before method");



        requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder().
                                                setBaseUri("https://xxx/api/data/v8.2/incidents").
                                                setRelaxedHTTPSValidation().
                                                setBasePath("HealthCheckApp/DetailsView").build()
                                                .auth().basic("userid", "pwd!");

    }

    @Test
    void GetIncidentAPI(){

        try{


            Response aresponse =  RestAssured.
                    given().
                    spec(requestSpecification).
                    when().
                    get().
                    then().
                    extract().
                    response();

            System.out.println("before getBody");

            String aresponseBody = aresponse.getBody().asString();

            System.out.println("response is " + aresponseBody);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.toString());

        }


    }

}
```

**Output**

**Getting Unknown Host Expection Error:** As you have provided the incorrect Host Name

[image]

Comment: Arpan, sorry for  the late reply. I am getting the following error: before method
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeMethod
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/restassured/common/mapper/factory/ObjectMapperFactory
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: @bnath002: The error are you getting is not related to this class as there is nothing imported from a package of ObjectMapperFactory.                                                    The reason for error is the respective dependency is not included in your project. add the respective dependency or Other reason could be There are two different version of the Jar included in your project and the the one jar that is more close to your project has no such method or class in the jar.

Comment: @bnath002: 1. The reason for error is the respective dependency is not included in your project. add the respective dependency or 2 second reason could be there are two different versions of the Jar included in your project and the one jar that is more close to your project has no such method or class in the jar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342163/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64/58399120#58399120

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below link. I have explained with the code:-

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343693/timeout-error-in-restassured-whereas-the-service-giving-response-in-postman-soap/58392345#58392345](http://rest-assured%20timeout)