# Error Cause: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My problem is that when I downloaded android studio when I try to build I'm getting the same error "Cause: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64"

I tried to include commons-codec.jar

```
org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.collectFailures(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:65)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:39)
    at org.gradle.initialization.exception.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:29)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
```

And that is just a beginning of errors. No code lines will help, cause when I open only with a hello world it shows me the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please describe the error you get a bit more (including, if possible, the line in which it occurs), and what relation does it have to the code snippet you attached? Also, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342163/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-codec-binary-base64

Comment: I saw this one and that's why I tried commons - codec.jar:D, i'll try to add more information .

Comment: I tried to reinstall it and that's not even helping... I don't even know what should I do.. As I can understand does errors only comes when I try to open emulator..